Node version not supported for Angular (macOS)
I installed angular cli and when I run ng version it gives me this output:
**Angular CLI: 17.3.5
Node: 21.7.3 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0
OS: darwin arm64
Angular: undefined
... 
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1703.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         17.3.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   17.3.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          17.3.5 (cli-only)
rxjs                         7.8.1
    
Warning: The current version of Node (21.7.3) is not supported by Angular.**

How can I fix the "UNSUPPORTED" problem.
Thanks!

Use LTS version. Currently 20.12.2

Here is the compatibility list for angular version, https://angular.io/guide/versions
install it accordingly, in mac you can also install nvm it is a good tool if you are working around different project with different node version.
